# Start tomcat9 on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

Hi ill try to start my tomcat 9 by eclipse and i get this error.

I look the mesaghe and say somthing about catalina.jar but i dont see any error there.

Anyona nows how fix this??

Thax and regards.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SitioWeb]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:657)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SitioWeb]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The
>   servlets named [Log] and [lib.Log] are both mapped to the url-pattern
>   [/Log] which is not permitted     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:328)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2428)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1991)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1985)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1156)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5003)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     ... 27 more
>
> sep 03, 2017 4:33:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal GRAVE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:657)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     ... 13 more
>
> sep 03, 2017 4:33:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:657)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
>
> sep 03, 2017 4:33:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
>   INFORMACIÓN: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] sep 03, 2017
>   4:33:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFORMACIÓN:
>   Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] sep 03, 2017 4:33:11 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFORMACIÓN:
>   Parando servicio [Catalina] sep 03, 2017 4:33:11 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFORMACIÓN: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] sep 03, 2017 4:33:11 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFORMACIÓN: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [Log] and [lib.Log] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/Log] which is not permitted at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded` - I guess you should start with correcting this in your code.

Comment: Thx @ErvinSzilagyi now its running